# How to display a json list on angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i'm having a problem to display a element of a JSON in the html

Here is the JSON

```
peopleList: [
    {
        name: 'John',
        address: 'Street A, 143',
        sons: [{
            First: "Jack",
            Second: "Jane",
            Third: "Maria"
        }]
    }]
```

And here is the html

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peopleList">
    <span class="">name: {{people.name}}</span><br>
    <span class="">sons: {{people.sons}}</span>
</div>
```

And this show Sons: [{"First": "Jack", "Second": "Jane", "Third": "Maria", "_id": "5604e8e474758451s6d813"}]

I have tried to use

```
people.sons.First
```

but didn't showed anything

Comment: try this: `{{people[0].sons[0].First}}`

Comment: what depends are `ng-repeat="name in names"` and people?. Or, does they depend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-repeat iteration looks kinda suspicious to me, try below

```
<div  ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span class="">name: {{name.name}}</span><br>
   <span class="">sons: {{name.sons.First}}</span>

 </div>
```

If you want to iterate Sons then it may look like below

```
<div  ng-repeat="name in names">
   <span class="">name: {{name.name}}</span><br>
   <span class="" ng-repeat="son in name.sons">
                 sons First: {{son.First}}
                 sons Second: {{son.Second}}                       
                 sons Third: {{son.Third}}                       
    </span>

 </div>
```

Comment: I think it should be `name in people`

Comment: Good Point! OP has not shown what scope variable he is using. I was thinking same but though just an idea of iterating object may lead him to find answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
{{people.sons[0].First}}
```

if you need to show just the first son.

This is because your `sons` property is an array (which is a bit odd - it implies that you have a 2nd *set* of sons? :-)). The `[0]` selects the set and the `.First` selects `Jack`

Comment: I think it should be `name in people`

Comment: @Satpal - thanks! I think OP seemed worried more about the sons part (the result and trials are more around that)

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <span class="">name: {{name.name}}</span><br>
   <span class="">sons: {{name.sons.First}}</span>
```

Comment: I have tried this and didn't worked, maybe i had made some mistake on the syntax haha

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating over `names` into `name`, so if you have a json array in `names` and if you want to render,according to your example please use `name.name` `name.sons` in the html inside ng-repeat

Comment: Hmmm, Okay, i will try, Thanks!